# JDBC template throws NullPointerException when no rows found

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I have a query to sum numeric values from single column:

```
int numberOfDays = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject
("select sum(number_of_days) from business_trip where name = ? and surname = ? and type = ?",new Object[]{name,surname,"UE"},Integer.class);
```

It works fine as long as there is a business trip of UE category for selected user. Then it sums trip days correctly. However, if there are no trips of UE category, instead of zero I'm getting **NullPointerException**. I can place this line inside try/catch but that would be a workaround. I would like to figure out why NPE is thrown in such case.

```
*2016-11-24 11:13:02.613 ERROR 8316 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.tfb.dao.BusinessTripDAO.getKrajoweTripsDaysForEmployee(BusinessTripDAO.java:59) ~[classes/:na]*
```

Comment: and line 59 is the one with the `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your select statement to

```
"select coalesce(sum(number_of_days), 0) from business_trip where name = ? and surname = ? and type = ?"
```

This way, if you get null it will be transformed to 0.

Comment: I think that since `queryForObject` returns an `Object` (which can be null), then your query statement do not find any rows to sum up, so instead of `0` it returns `null`. And this is perfectly logical for an Object (`Integer`), but not for a primitive type (int). If you change your initial code to `Integer numberOfDays = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject
("select sum(number_of_days) from business_trip where name = ? and surname = ? and type = ?",new Object[]{name,surname,"UE"},Integer.class);` do you still get the NPE? It is like trying the following: `int i = (Integer) null;`

Comment: I did some research and I found that an sql query that performs any kind 'math' (SUM in this case) will throw NLP when encounter  a NULL value instead of numeric one. Also: replacing int with Integer didn't change anything.